# Establishing a new service leader and informing the lead

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, distributed-system, jgroups

I have a distributed system design problem. The problem brief is

> We have many clients to a service. The service needs to be
>   fault-tolerant and so it will have many replicas. When a client can no
>   longer access the service it will switch to a replica and inform all
>   the other clients will switch to the same replica. (It is not
>   acceptable to load-balance across the replicas as the replicas' data
>   values are not exactly the same but all the clients must return the
>   same data values at all times.)

My current design is to have the client, on failing to reach the service, ask for a new service leader. When a new service leader is established it will then notify all the clients to use it.

As with many distributed coordination designs I need a distributed group manager. I am considering the use of JGroups and/or Apache Zookeeper in a solution.

Is there an existing recipe or recipes that I should be looking at to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you control the services, then have the services do a [leader election](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.2/recipes.html#sc_leaderElection) among themselves.  Clients will watch for changes in the elected leader, and send requests to the current service leader.

If you don't control the services, then have the client's elect a leader, and that client will be responsible for maintaining a node in zookeeper which points to the current leader service.  All clients will watch this node to be notified of changes to which node is the master.  The leader client will have to be able to check the health of the leader service somehow.

> but all the clients must return the same data values at all times

This isn't possible with zookeeper, or in most distributed systems.  It will take some time (usually only milli seconds) for a change in service leader to propagate to all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

This seems readymade for zookeeper. You can have your clients all set a watch on a common znode (which would contain replica info). If a client changes the znode, all other clients would receive a one-time notification about the change.

Take a look at http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperProgrammers.html#ch_zkWatches